# INVALID_SESSION_ID error while trying to save Lead or Contact

Tags: rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, session

We have developed an mobile app for Salesforce with OAuth and using the REST API V34 and released it to the customer. And customer can able to login to salesforce from the app but when he tries to add a Lead or Contact from the app then he is getting the below error.

**[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]**

But I have not faced any such issue when i tried to do the same using my test developer account or whenever signing up a new account. And i googled about this issue and come across the solution from the below link

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205360&language=en_US

But we can not ask every customer to follow from the above solution.

Please let me know if it can be resolved the developer side.

Comment: What is your Salesforce session timeout  value?

Comment: The time out value in our developer account is 8 hours. And we are not getting these kind of error when we test our app.

Answer (score 1):

If it's all working in a Developer Edition, and it's not simply an expired session (a situation you can easily replicate, code for and test in Developer Edition), then the most likely problem is the user account that the customer is using. They should check that it has API access enabled, and create permissions for Lead and Contact.

Comment: I tried with salesforce professional edition today and got the error like "API access disabled for you org". My doubt is is this two error are different. And what has to be done to resolve these issues.